# Kobo Libra images appear very small

Tags: epub, kobo

I have a new Kobo Libra and bought 2 online `epub` books.
I transferred them onto Kobo by using `Calibre`. When opening the eBook the layout is fine except that all images appear very small!? I've opened the the eBook in `Calibre` and there everything looks fine, the images are scaled to a readable/viewable size.

Is this an issue with Kobo, the `.epub` format or something else?

Comment: I have the same problem with the Kobo Aura ONE, for what it's worth.

Comment: I have the same problem with the new Kobo Libra 2. My guess is that this is on Kobo. I didn't have this problem on my previous Sony e-reader.

Answer (score 1):

I found a hacky solution to the problem by editing the eBook's styling using `Calibre`.

Importing the ebook and then right click on `Edit book` which opens the actual contents of the book. Now the actual formatting is done via a stylesheet (in my case called `stylesheet.css`).

In this stylesheet there are the generated properties for the image sizes, e.g.

```
.calibre95 {
    height: 229px;
    width: 226px
}
```

Now the images can be adjusted by editing the height and width of every relevant entry. I've done this via a small Python script since Calibre generated a new entry for each image and there were a lot.

I know this is not a general solution but might help some to fix there books as well

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this exact problem for DAYS and what i did to fix it was so dumb - i looked at the files on my device through my computer's file explorer, and noticed that the two books that were experiencing issues had two files in thier folders - a .kepub.epub and a .epub file. I deleted the .kepub.epub file on a whim and... Full-sized, fixed, beautiful covers!